# Convert multiple logos into the_custom_logo

Tags: functions, logo

When the page first loads, the logo is quite big but when I scroll down the menu height reduces and the logo gets smaller. This is if I am just referencing the logo using bloginfo() but I want to be able to modify the logo through customizer if necessary.

I called the logo like so:

```
the_custom_logo();
```

which shows up but it doesn't get smaller when scrolling down like when I use the the below. Is it possible to convert the below into the_custom_logo() ?

```
<div class="logo">
    <a id="logo" href="#" data-height="110" data-padding="0"><img class="logo-main scale-with-grid" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/animals2.png" data-retina="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/retina-animals2.png" data-height="209" alt="animals2">
    <img class="logo-sticky scale-with-grid" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/animals2.png" data-retina="content/animals2/images/retina-animals2.png" data-height="209" alt="animals2">
    <img class="logo-mobile scale-with-grid" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/animals2.png" data-retina="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/retina-animals2.png" data-height="209" alt="animals2">
    <img class="logo-mobile-sticky scale-with-grid" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/animals2.png" data-retina="content/animals2/images/retina-animals2.png" data-height="209" alt="animals2"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`get_custom_logo`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_custom_logo/) filter to customize the HTML of the custom logo to whatever you want. For instance, you can do something like so:

You can further use the `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filter to get the image `src` of the logo. The problem is using it. The example code below uses a class to store the image source as a property so it can be used in a different filter.

```
namespace WordPress\StackExchange;
class logo {
  protected $src = '';
  public function init() {
    \add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', [ $this, 'img_atts' ] , 10, 3 );
    \add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', [ $this, 'wpse_custom_logo' ], 10, 2 );
  }
  public function image_atts( $attr, $attachment, $size ) {
    if( 'custom-logo' ]=== $attr[ 'class' ]  ) {
      $this->src = $attr[ 'src' ];
    }
    return $attr;
  }
  public function wpse_custom_logo( $html, $blog_id ) {
    return sprintf( '
      <div class="logo">
        <a id="logo" href="#" data-height="110" data-padding="0">
          <img class="logo-main scale-with-grid" src="%1$s" data-retina="%2$s" data-height="209" alt="animals2">
          <img class="logo-sticky scale-with-grid" src="%1$s" data-retina="%2$s" data-height="209" alt="animals2">
          <img class="logo-mobile scale-with-grid" src="%1$s" data-retina="%2$s" data-height="209" alt="animals2">
          <img class="logo-mobile-sticky scale-with-grid" src="%1$s" data-retina="%2$s" data-height="209" alt="animals2">
        </a>
      </div>',
    \esc_url( $this->src ),
    \esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/content/animals2/images/retina-animals2.png )'
    );
  }
}
\add_action( 'init', [ new logo(), 'init' ] );
```

This would go in your functions.php. Although, since the 4 images are all the same, there's probably a better way to do this.

Comment: Thank you! What if I still want the user to be able to upload their own logo like you can with`the_custom_logo()`? I see that in your example you hard coded the logo url `esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/animals2.png' ),`